# Google maps traffic prediction API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to implement the google traffic prediction described in the link, with the maps api?
[maps traffic prediction](http://lifehacker.com/381077/google-maps-predicts-traffic-conditions-for-your-travel-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Here's the API documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#TrafficLayer

Traffic prediction is not part of the API. It *is* included in Google Maps (their own, not others' maps via the API), so it will be possible to use undocumented calls to get the data. But they don't like people doing that and it could have unintended consequences.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick whats updated regarding traffic predication api?

Answer (score 3):

the question and the accepted answer are from 2012.

Since October 2015 it *IS* possible to get routes and predicted travel times for future trips.

You can supply `departure_time` with your route plan request. Note that this feature only works if you connect using an API key.

It's based on historical data, and when the trip is in the near future, it uses live traffic data.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#RequestParameters